# How do I make gb4e.sty's commands overlay aware for beamer?

Tags: beamer, linguistics, gb4e

I use the [`gb4e`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gb4e) package to set numbered examples. I want to put these on slides made with beamer. According to the beamer userguide I can make any command overlay specification aware using this in my preamble:

```
\renewcommand<>{⟨existing command name⟩}[⟨argument number⟩][⟨default optional value⟩]{⟨text⟩}
```

I tried to do this with `gb4e`'s \ex command. I tried the following:

```
\newcommand<>{\ex}[][]{\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
```

I thought that would be right, because gb4e defines \ex as follows:

```
\def\ex{\@ifnextchar [{\@ex}{\item}}
```

With that in my preamble my document doesn't compile. Am I misunderstanding something about how this works?

Comment: You need to surround the `\renewcommand` with `\makeatletter`/`\makeatother`.  If you haven't done that in your document, it will fail to compile.

Comment: That was silly of me. Now it compiles, but hasn't made the commands overlay aware.

Answer (score 8):

Unfortunately, `gb4e`'s example commands are more complicated than this, and are defined with delimited arguments using `\def`.  I'm not sure that they can be made overlay aware so easily.  The easiest way to uncover example items line by line is simply to use the `\pause` command.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{gb4e}
\resetcounteronoverlays{exx}


\begin{document}
\begin{frame}{A frame}
  \begin{exe}
  \ex\label{Ex1}
  \begin{xlist}
     \ex[]{ This is an example}
     \pause
     \ex[*]{This example ungrammatical is.}
     \pause
     \ex[]{Another one.}
  \end{xlist}
  \end{exe}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe I can't do it then. I'll just design my slides around the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The `\@ifnextchar` is just to define a command with optional argument. Try

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand<>{\ex}{\@ifnextchar[{\@ex}{\item}}
\makeatother
```

Can you add a minimal example of what you're trying to do?